# Default constructor, which one is more correct / idiomatic?

Tags: c++11, vector, initialization

Is there any difference between:

```
class A {
    std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3};
public:
    // more stuff...    
};

A a; // implicit default constructor

class B {
    std::vector<int> vec;
public:
    B() : vec {1, 2, 3} {}
    // more stuff...
}

B b; // default constructor
```

Which one is faster / more idiomatic / correct in C++14?

In my class I have 3 members: a `static const` initialized inside the class, a boolean initialized to true and a non initialized `std::vector`.

My two constructors initialize the `std::vector` and, when necessary I change the boolean to false. I want the default constructor to initialize the `std::vector` with 0? Wich options from above is more correct?

If I initialized the `std::vector` member, what would happen If I did this?
PS: My class is not a POD.

```
class B {
    std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3}; // already initialized vector
public:
    B(std::vector<int> const & data)
        : vec {data} // would it still be initialization or copy-assignment?
    {}
}

B b; //default constructor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no practical difference between your first two examples.  In-class initializers are useful when you want to use the same initializer in multiple constructors; constructor initializer lists are mandatory when you want to use different inititalizers in different constructors.

When you have both an in-class initializer and a constructor member initializer, the in-class initializer is ignored for that constructor.  There's still just one initialization and no assignment.